# Why is the my.cnf file on the server incomplete or has very few entries?

Tags: mysql, ssh, plesk

I have accessed a clients server (plesk) via ssh to view/edit the my.cnf and php.ini files
if i view them using vi the file seem to be virtualy empty of entries ? see screenshot.

Not sure whether this is an access issue or the files are the right files any help would be appreciated

Thanks

[image]

Comment: So it's just using the defaults for the rest of the properties. What else were you expecting? You can usually find some examples under /usr/share/mysql/

Comment: @Rup i was expecting things like this:

Comment: # The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port  = 3306
socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1500M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.16
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.16/data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Rup already mentioned in his comment, the my.cnf file contains only these few lines. It is completely fine, mysql server is able to start also without any config file - in that case it uses the defaults plus whatever is on the commandline.
To see what config files mysqld reads and what defaults it uses, just run:

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

and it will produce report containing for example this:

```
mysqld  Ver 5.0.51a-24-log for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Debian))

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf

The following groups are read: mysql_cluster mysqld server mysqld-5.0

Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- -----------------------------
help                              TRUE
...
wait_timeout                      3600

To see what values a running MySQL server is using, type
'mysqladmin variables' instead of 'mysqld --verbose --help'.
```

Comment: many thanks for this answer very helpful , i have run the commands and can now see the config settings, thanks again